# Move uploaded file

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

As I mentioned in Node.JS fs.rename can not move files in right way. And it should be solved with stream piping. Please verify this code and answer questions in comments:

```
var fs = require("fs");

var moveFile = function(sourceFile, destFile, callback) {
var sourceStream = fs.createReadStream(sourceFile);

sourceStream.on('error', function(err) {
    // Is sourceStream closed? Or should we close it manually?
    // Is destStream also closed? Or should we close it manually?
    callback(err); // moveFile() - Problem copying file
});

sourceStream.on('end', function() {
    // sourceStream is closed
    // Should we close destStream manually? 
    destStream.end();
    // Should we use sync version? 
    fs.unlinkSync(sourceFile);
    callback(null, true); // File successfully moved
});

var destStream = fs.createWriteStream(destFile);
destStream.on('error', function(err) {
    // Is destStream closed? 
    // destStream.end();
    callback(err); //moveFile() - Could not open writestream
});

sourceStream.pipe(destStream);};
```

Comment: New version on GitHub http://github.com/hellboy81/move_file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a once over:

- Your indenting is iffy `var sourceStream = fs.createReadStream(sourceFile);` should be indented and everything under it within that function
- `sourceStream` is auto-closed because *If autoClose is set to true (default behavior), on error or end the file descriptor will be closed automatically.*
- `fs.unlinkSync(sourceFile);` <- It is more idiomatic to use the async version
- `sourceStream.pipe(destStream);};` <- Please use a beautifier or somesuch
- This:

  ```
  destStream.on('error', function(err) {
      // Is destStream closed? 
      // destStream.end();
      callback(err); //moveFile() - Could not open writestream
  });
  ```

  can be replaced with

  ```
  destStream.on('error', callback );
  ```

  since `callback` is also a function that can take `err` as a parameter

All in all, I would go with something like this(untested):

```
var fs = require("fs");

var moveFile = function(sourceFile, destFile, callback) {
  //Set up streams
  var sourceStream = fs.createReadStream(sourceFile),
      destStream = fs.createWriteStream(destFile);
  //Set up error handling
  sourceStream.on('error', callback);
  destStream.on('error', callback);
  //Set up unlinkHandler
  function unlinkHandler( err ){
    callback( err || null , err ? undefined : true ); 
  }
  //Set up end of source handling
  sourceStream.on('end', function() {
    destStream.end();
    fs.unlinkSync(sourceFile, unlinkHandler);
  });
  //Start moving
  sourceStream.pipe(destStream);
};
```